# How do I write a comment to a PropertiesConfiguration file?

Tags: configuration-files, apache-commons

Given one of these instances: org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration I want to write a comment.  How?

```
pc = new PropertiesConfiguration();

writeComment("this is a comment about the stuff below"); // HOW DO I WRITE THIS?
pc.addProperty("label0", myString);
writeComment("end of the stuff that needed a comment.");
```

**Edit: I have a crude solution.  Hopefully it can be improved upon.**

---

Here's the best I could do.  It leaves an extraneous line in the file.

```
pc = new PropertiesConfiguration();
writeComment(pc, "The following needed a comment so this is a comment.");
pc.addProperty(label0, stuff0);
writeComment(pc, "End of the stuff that needed a comment.");

...
 private void writeComment(PropertiesConfiguration pc, String s)
 {
    String propertyName = String.format("%s%d", "comment", this.commentNumber++);

    pc.getLayout().setComment(propertyName, s + " (" + propertyName + ")");

    // make a dummy property 
    pc.addProperty(propertyName, "."); 
         // put in a dummy right-hand-side value so the = sign is not lonely 
 }
```

One of the problems with this approach is that the PropertiesConfiguration doc is a little vague about the layout.  It does not explicitly say that the comment will appear above the dummy line so there seems to be the risk that PropertiesConfiguration is free to re-arrange the file on subsequent invocations.  I have not even seen an guarantee that property line order is preserved so I cannot guarantee that the comment (and dummy line) will always be above the property that the comment applies to: property `label0`.  Of course, I'm being a little paranoid here.  However, the doc does say that layouts are not guaranteed to remain unmodified.    **Hopefully somebody can come up with something without the dummy line and a Java doc or website guarantee on the position of the comment relative to the property it is meant to comment on.**  Edit: You might wonder why I would create a dummy property instead of just attaching the comment to one of the properties that would already be in the file.  The reason is because I want a comment to introduce a block of properties and changes (new ones, or a switch in the order) are possible.  I don't want to create a maintenance problem.  My comment should say "this is the section for data mining results" or "this is the section for the schedule" and I should never have to revisit this.

Answer (score 0):

Comment like this?

```
# This is comment
```

Answer (score -1):

The PropertiesConfiguration [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html) documents

```
 Blank lines and lines starting with character '#' or '!' are skipped.
```

**EDIT**: Ok, you want to write the comment from code. Maybe - if you just need to write a property file - you can use the [PropertiesConfiguration.PropertiesWriter](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.PropertiesWriter.html) and its [writeComment](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.PropertiesWriter.html#writeComment%28java.lang.String%29) method like this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.properties");
PropertiesWriter propWriter = new PropertiesWriter(writer, ';');

propWriter.writeComment("Example properties");
propWriter.writeProperty("prop1","foo");
propWriter.writeProperty("prop2", "bar");

propWriter.close();
```

The property file will look like this:

```
# Example properties
prop1 = foo
prop2 = bar
```

**Update**

Summarized: The PropertiesConfiguration does not provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I don't know how to provide the Java Writer object to the PropertiesWriter.  I don't know how to get a Java Writer from my existing PropertiesConfiguration.

Comment: Your solution seems to be to use the inner class.  I already have a lot of code that uses the outer class.  It would be good if there were a way to get the FileWriter from the outer class so that I can use the inner class for only the comments.  Then I could leave the rest of my code unchanged.

Comment: @broiyan Unfortunatly my solution does not fit together with the usage of the outer `PropertiesConfiguration` class. I can not find any possibility to place a comment _after_ a property. Sorry, I am out!

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to put the comment after the dummy property.  I just prefer for documentation writers to say that they did not use a random number generator to decide if the comment will be before/after the dummy property.  I am joking but I also serious about quality documentation.

Comment: @broiyan As I understood the `pc.getLayout().setComment("label0", "some comment")` will place a comment to the `label0` property. So you are perfectly able to comment single properties. But you can not place your '_end of the stuff that needed a comment_' after a property (or section of properties) - so therefore you introduced this dummy property. As I don't know how the properties are sorted when beeing written I don't know if that works as you expect (the JavaDoc of the PropertiesConfigurationLayout class mentions that the class is _far away from being perfect_).

Comment: Of course it works the way I expect: comment0, dummyProperty0, label0, "real data for property label0", comment1, dummyProperty1. What I do not want is undocumented behavior that results in dummyProperty0, comment0, label0, "real data for property label0", dummyProperty1, comment1.

Comment: That's why I say that there may be a documentation problem.

Comment: Having a look at the [PropertiesConfigurationLayout.save](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.java#PropertiesConfigurationLayout.save%28java.io.Writer%29) method you can see that the comment will always be written above the property (everything else would be really unusual).

Comment: I am against reading source code.  It would be easy for developers to introduce a non-backwards compatible change by modifying that source.  If it is Javadoc documented to be above the property then they would hesitate to change the order.

Comment: @broiyan This discussion will lead to nothing. I took my time to help you understand what is going on. The library you use works as I described in my answer and my comments. I doubt that obvious behaviour will ever be documented in JavaDoc - if you want to know what's really going on you have to look into code (JavaDoc might be out of date). I will update my answer so that it fits to your question - and then I am done.

Comment: K. Claszen, Thank you for the help.  My interpretation of the documentation is that you should expect the unexpected. To quote: "This is a very simple implementation, which is far away from being perfect, i.e. the original layout of a properties file won't be reproduced in all cases." Furthermore if you call addProperty() first and setComment() second, the comment still appears first.  That's not obvious.

Comment: @broiyan It is convent that a comment appears BEFORE the content (property/code/whatever). I have never seen code or configuration comments AFTER the content. Thus if you add a comment to a property I strongly expect that the library will place the comment BEFORE the property. The order of the calls (first addProperty() / second setComment()) is just natural because you can not set the comment without knowing the property you would like to comment.

Comment: With version 2, you can use setFooterComment, but this obviously only sets a comment at the bottom of the file